# Javascript framework for pushstate "hijax"

Tags: javascript, ajax, javascript-framework, pushstate, hijax

All our apps are php mvc and with a very simple js behavioral layer on top at the client side. We want to structure the javascript more and stop requesting "snippets" to execute simple behaviour (like, loading different jquery plugins all over the place). We do not use javascript MVC frameworks and looking into a best-fit solution for our new apps.

One of the most appealing solution is to keep rendering server side for us, like [Twitter does](http://engineering.twitter.com/2012/12/implementing-pushstate-for-twittercom_7.html). They call it "Hijax + server-side rendering". We prefer not to have a full blown mvc framework in javascript but these quotes from the blog are very appealing to us:

> By contract, our components attach themselves to a single DOM node, listen to events via delegation, fire events on the DOM, and those events are broadcast to other components via DOM event bubbling. [...] Secondly, all of our components are defined using AMD.

We have been trying to build something our own, but without high level javascript expertise we can't get far in this. Something like [jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/) seems a good solution for very simple cases too.

We are looking for:

1. A UI / data segregation to loosly couple XHR with the DOM
2. Event driven UI, so devs can attach listeners to all kind of DOM objects

Is there something like a javascript framework for this? With `pushState` getting more and more attention, I hope something will be available. Any ideas?

Comment: IMO Twitter's approach is fairly miserable. Back in June I wrote a [demo js bookmarklet](http://dist.meekostuff.net/meeko-twitter/) and [article](http://www.meekostuff.net/blog/Twitter-without-Hashbangs/) showing how they could have migrated to `pushState` by progressively enhancing mobile.twitter.com. I used my [HTMLDecor](http://github.com/meekostuff/HTMLDecor/) js framework and the demo only took a few days. How many man-months did Twitter take to migrate?

Comment: Interesting comment Sean :-) However, we do not transit to js hijax because of wished performance gain, we sometimes need behavioural scripting where html can't do the job and we want to minimize our server side applications. That's why we thought hijax would be a really good fit for us. And when javascript is disabled, you should get a fallback of the "old" full-page rendered app. And I fully agree with "hashbangs are dead": they are inflexible and progressive enhancement becomes a no-go

Comment: That's another issue with the new twitter.com - there is no way to tweet if js is disabled. Progressive enhancement as an after-thought.

Comment: Well, twitter has released [flight](http://twitter.github.com/flight/) - a lightweight, component-based JavaScript framework that maps behavior to DOM nodes. It doesn't sound like `pushState` is integrated but you might be able to combine it with `jquery-pjax`.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you're looking for? What is jquery-pjax missing that you need?

Comment: @JefferyTo as far as I see it, jquery-pjax tightly couples UI with events and data. You have a single element that's listened for `click`, that should be an `<a>` element with an `href` which contents in injected in a DOM node where you have a jquery selector for. What if I have a chain of events, if I don't use an `<a>` element, if I want to update two blocks of html in my page etc? There are more complicated things than only the `<a>` -> click -> block chain. I think that Flight, where Sean points at, is a good example of the glue to create this kind of thing. I will certainly have a look!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to checkout [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js) and 
[Amplifyjs](http://amplifyjs.com/) (and possibly [microjs](http://microjs.com/#) for some components to put together)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to answer your question to the best of my ability.  With that being said, I will say that your question is *very* broad and quite ambiguous.  You have not successfully communicated what exactly you're looking for in a JavaScript library.  You mentioned a lot of different topics that are all complicated and each exist to server a specific purpose in client-side development.  While there maybe be implementations of all of these concepts in the wild, there is no one clear-cut answer to solve all your problems.

I'll start with your first point of "UI / data segregation".  This concept is really about separation of concerns.  You want your UI to exist separately from your data.  What you're really looking for here is for your HTML to reflect the current state of your data model.  You also want this to happen automatically for you.  This is a very common workflow with an MVC design pattern.  JavaScript has several options available to you:  [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org), [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org), [EmberJS](http://emberjs.com), and the list goes on...

In my personal experience of using quite a few of these different frameworks, I would suggest Backbonejs for it's flexible and lightweight nature.  In Backbone we have the concept of a "View" that *can* be tied directly to a data model.  It also supports your desired concept of "pushSate" through it's Routes mechanism.

The "Event driven UI" portion can be handled by any number of different JavaScript libraries.  jQuery is probably the most popular library to attach events to "all kinds of dom elements".  Backbone.js also allows easy setup of event delegation (through event bubbling) with its View object.

In short, if you're looking to add structure to your JavaScript... it really depends *exactly* what it is you want.  For just simple things, a little bit of handcrafted jQuery will do.  If you REALLY want a more MVC style app, that has potential to grow, MVC frameworks like Backbone are the way to go.